# Ocean Acidification - The effect of CO2 concentration on the pH of the ocean

Tags: atmosphere, oceanography, carbon-cycle, ecology

I'm confused about how increased CO2 concentration in the atmosphere affects the pH of the ocean.

The increase in CO2 concentration means the pH of the ocean will decrease (by several chemical rxns). However, as there is more CO2 in the atmosphere, ocean temperatures will rise meaning the ocean will absorb less CO2, likely increasing the pH of the ocean...

In short, the rise in CO2 seems to have two contrasting effects on the pH of the ocean... am I interpreting this correctly? If yes, why is the pH of the ocean forecasted to decrease so much in the future?

For reference, here is the article I read: https://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/ocean-acidification-25822734/

Comment: Re *ocean temperatures will rise meaning the ocean will absorb less CO2, likely increasing the pH of the ocean* This doesn't quite make sense. This would make sense if your claim was that rising temperatures caused the oceans to expel already absorbed CO2. But you didn't make that claim. Per your claim, that the oceans will absorb CO2 at a lesser rate means the pH will decline more slowly.

Comment: no answer here but somewhat related in Chemistry SE: [Could we reach a pH of 4.9 by blowing through straws?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/76223/16035)

Comment: Ahh yea I reposted the question here... didn't think they'd migrate it here. I'll take this post down.

Comment: Being aware of the rate of the processes would help you. There are essentially thousands of processes (with some more important than others) having opposite effect in any complex system.